# how to find available dates with laravel query?

Tags: laravel

I have multiple halls. I have to search halls for booking with given dates and time. How i can find available dates from data with laravel query.

```
            $getData = Booking::where('category_id', '=', $categoryID)->
                    where('booking_time', '=', $time)
                ->whereDate('date_from', '>=', $startDate)
                ->whereDate('date_to', '<=', $endDate)
                ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to know the available dates you need 1) a range to of dates consider and 2) the unavailable dates. Then you compare them.

You could create a calendar table in your db with all dates for the next x years stored in it, then just compare that to your bookings. Or you could do it in PHP, like this:

```
$availableDates['morning'] = iterator_to_array(new DatePeriod(
     new DateTime('2019-01-01'),
     new DateInterval('P1D'),
     new DateTime('2019-12-31')
));

$availableDates['afternoon'] = $availableDates['morning'];

$unavailableDates = [];

foreach(Booking::where('category_id', $category_id)->get() as $booking) {

    $unavailableDates[$booking->booking_time] += iterator_to_array(new DatePeriod(
         new DateTime($booking->date_from),
         new DateInterval('P1D'),
         new DateTime($booking->date_to)
    ));

}

 function compareDates(DateTime $a, DateTime $b) { return $a->getTimestamp() - $b->getTimestamp(); }

 $available['morning'] = array_udiff($availableDates['morning'],$unavailableDates,'compareDates');

 $available['afternoon'] = array_udiff($availableDates['afternoon'],$unavailableDates,'compareDates');
```

There's probably some efficiency you could gain by cutting out a couple of loops but this should get you started.

Comment: How to count this query.. like in my code i am checking in if statement about any available date?

Comment: You could put all of the above code into a function called getAvailableDates() on the Booking::model. If you aren't clear how to do this then you need to go back to learning the basics before you continue.

Comment: Okay i have to put this code in funtion in model class and then call it here with params of start date and end date.

Comment: Probably at the `+= iter...` line. Add a check to make sure both are arrays.